# How to include a NuGet package in Visual Studio Installer Project

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installation, nuget

I'm developing an Installer project that wraps third-party executable file to customise installation according to requirements.

I want to include executable file in a civilised manner. We have a local NuGet repository, and using it as a source for executable file seemed like a good idea. But it turns out that Visual Studio Installer Setup Project does not support NuGet.

Adding the executable to our GIT repository is something I would like to avoid.

I tried to install the NuGet package using commandline NuGet interface in a PreBuildEvent but pre-build validation failed due to missing files.

Is there a straightforward way to include an executable file in Installer project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

Make a normal target that depends on the nuget package. This should cause the contents of the package to end up in the build output.

Target the build output of that project with the installer project.

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to include the executable in resulting MSI file (judging by the size). But how do I target the executable? SourcePath and TargetName properties are empty. Anyplace I can read on this?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I managed to use MakeMsi to wrap InstallShield exe in a MSI file, so I won't have to deal with Installer Project.